# How to eliminate this error?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a .js code that returns an invalid module id. Here is my code, can someone please tell me how to eliminate the error?

```js
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/OrderController.getAccounts';
import PURCHASE_REQUEST_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Purchase_Request__c';
import ACCOUNT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Purchase_Request__c. Account_Related__c';
import QUANTITY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Purchase_Request__c. Quantity__c';
import MERCHANDISE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Purchase_Request__c. Merchandise_to_Request__c';
import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Purchase_Request__c. Status__c';
export default class OrderController extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId
    error
    account
    quantity
    accounts
    accountStatus
    accountObject=[]
    @wire(getAccounts)
    wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.accounts = data.map((record)=> ({
                value:record.Id,
                label:record.Name
            }))
            this.accountObject = data;
            this.error = undefined
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error
            this.accounts = undefined
        }
    }
    handleAccountChange(event) {
        this.account = event.target.value
        this.accountStatus = this.accountObject.find(item => item.Id === this.account).Account_Status__c
    }
    handleQuantityChange(event) {
        this.quantity = event.target.value
    }
    create() {
        if(!this.quantity || this.quantity < 0) {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Ooopps',
                    message:'Fix all the necessary fields.',
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            )
        } else {
            if (this.accountStatus == 'Approved') {
                const fields = {};
                fields[ACCOUNT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.account;
                fields[QUANTITY_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.quantity;
                fields[MERCHANDISE_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.recordId;
                fields[STATUS_FIELD.fieldApiName] = 'New';
                const recordInput = { apiName: PURCHASE_REQUEST_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };
                createRecord(recordInput)
                    .then((record) => {
                        this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value = null;
                        this.template.querySelector('lightning-combobox').value = '';
                        this.dispatchEvent(
                            new ShowToastEvent({
                                title: 'Success',
                                message: 'Purchase Request has been created unfortunately the minimum amount to start production has not been met. We will reach out to you once we have reached the minimum amount.',
                                variant: 'success'
                            })
                        );
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error)
                        this.dispatchEvent(
                            new ShowToastEvent({
                                title: 'Error creating record',
                                message: error,
                                variant: 'error'
                            })
                        );
                    });
            } else {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Ooopps',
                        message:'Your account is not approved for use.',
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                )
            }
        }
    }
}\
```

Here is the error:

> LWC1500: Invalid module id "@salesforce/schema/Purchase_Request__c. Account_Related__c". (6:26)
> LWC1500: Invalid module id "@salesforce/schema/Purchase_Request__c. Quantity__c". (7:27)
> LWC1500: Invalid module id "@salesforce/schema/Purchase_Request__c. Status__c". (9:25)
> LWC1500: Invalid module id "@salesforce/schema/Purchase_Request__c. Merchandise_to_Request__c". (8:30

Comment: Remove spaces in import statements

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space after the dot between the object name and field name.

```
import ACCOUNT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Purchase_Request__c.Account_Related__c';
```

Etc.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @TieriaErde You fixed all four instances?

Comment: I got it working. Thank you!